# Not able to add more than 2000 records in excel file using batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I'm using the batch class to send an email with an attachment, but the issue is I'm able to add only 2000 records in single file. I have a huge amount of data so I'm getting multiple emails with different files.
My code is as follows:

```
    global class PurchaseDetailsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    //String customerRegion = 'Allied 10 EP MidAtlantic';
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Beacon_Acc_Number__c,Region_Mincron__c,Days_Since_Last_Purchase__c, Owner.Name, Date_Last_Purchase__c FROM Account WHERE Days_Since_Last_Purchase__c >= 30 AND Beacon_Acc_Number__c != NULL AND Date_Last_Purchase__c != NULL AND Region_Mincron__c != NULL' ;
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> accList){
    String header = 'Customer Number, Name, Days Since Last Purchase, Date Last Purchase, Owner Name\n';
    String finalstr = header;
    List<Purchase_Details__c> purchaseDetailsList = Purchase_Details__c.getall().values();
    Map<String,String[]> purchaseMap = new Map<String,String[]>();
    Map<String,List<Account>> accountMap = new Map<String,List<Account>>();
    for(Purchase_Details__c objPurchase : purchaseDetailsList){
      if(objPurchase.Email__c.contains(',')){
         String[] address = objPurchase.Email__c.split(',');
         purchaseMap.put(objPurchase.Name, address);
      }else{
         purchaseMap.put(objPurchase.Name,new String[] {objPurchase.Email__c});
      }

    }
    Map<String,Blob> emailFileMap = new Map<String,Blob>();
    for(Account acc : accList){
        String records = acc.Beacon_Acc_Number__c+',';
        if(acc.Name.contains(',')){
         String temp = acc.Name.remove(',');
         records+=temp+',';
        }else{
         records+=acc.Name+',';
        }

        records+=acc.Days_Since_Last_Purchase__c+',';
        Date d = acc.Date_Last_Purchase__c;
        records+=d.day()+'-'+d.month()+'-'+d.year()+',';
        records+=acc.Owner.Name+',';
        records +='\n';      
        finalstr = finalstr+records;
        if(acc.Region_Mincron__c != null){
         emailFileMap.put(acc.Region_Mincron__c,Blob.valueOf(finalstr));
        }
    }
    System.debug('-->'+emailFileMap.keySet().size());
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(String regionStr : purchaseMap.keySet()){


      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
      blob excel;
       if(emailFileMap.containsKey(regionStr) && emailFileMap.get(regionStr) != null){
         excel = emailFileMap.get(regionStr);
       }
       //blob excel = blob.valueOf(finalstr);
       attach.setBody(excel);
       attach.setFileName(regionStr+' file.csv');
       String subject = regionStr;
       //String body = 'Users who are not logged in since last 30 days';
       String body = 'Please find attached file for purchase details';
       String[] addressFromLabel = purchaseMap.get(regionStr);

       Messaging.singleEmailMessage Emailwithattch = new Messaging.singleEmailMessage();

       Emailwithattch.setSubject(subject);

       Emailwithattch.setToaddresses(addressFromLabel);

       Emailwithattch.setHtmlBody(body);     

       Emailwithattch.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});

       emails.add(Emailwithattch);



    }
      Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r =

      Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
  }    

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){         }   
  /*public void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
   Database.executeBatch(new SouthDivisionUsersBatch(), 2000);     
   }  */    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing batch as `Database.executeBatch(new PurchaseDetailsBatch(), 2000);` and run emails sending in the execute method. Therefore, you have batches of 2000 records each.

To send them all in one file you need to set `implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful`, add some variable to the class where you will store items, for example, `public List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();`. In the execute method just add completed items to that variable and send them all in finish method.

That should work properly for you.